# django autocomplete light - limiting choiches for foreign key fields with limit_choiches_to

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light in a django admin application but i cant get choiches correctly filtered for a fk field with `limit_choiches_to` argument: I still get the entire queryset. here's the code:

```
# autocomplete_light.py
from django.db.models import Q

import autocomplete_light

from myapp.models import MyClass
from otherapp.models import Deps


class MyClassAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    """ MyClass autocomplete widget class """
    choiches = MyModels.objects.filter(
            Q(dpt__in=Deps.MAIN_DEPARTMENTS),
            Q(user__is_active=True)
        )
    search_fields = ['^full_name', 'initials']
    attrs = {'placeholder': 'Type a name'}

autocomplete_light.register(MyClass, MyClassAutocomplete)




# admin.py
class SampleModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        link_attrs = {'cols': 105, 'rows': 3}
        model = SampleModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SampleModelAdminForm, self).__init__(
            *args, **kwargs
        )
        self.fields['my_fk'].widget = autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget(
            'MyClassAutocomplete'
        )
```

I also tried to override `choices_for_request` method in AutocompleteModelBase subclass:

```
def choices_for_request(self):
    return MyModels.objects.filter(
            Q(dpt__in=Deps.MAIN_DEPARTMENTS),
            Q(user__is_active=True)
    )
```

By this way I have the filtered queryset, but I loose the autocomplete feature (for every word that I type, e.g. 'Es', it starts to show me the choiches from the A letter)

Anybody can help me with that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo: `choiches` in

```
choiches = MyModels.objects.filter(
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more...?

Comment: It seems to work in this way:

    `def choices_for_request(self):
        self.choiches = MyModels.objects.filter(
            Q(dpt__in=Deps.MAIN_DEPARTMENTS),
            Q(user__is_active=True)
        )
 return super(MyModels, self).choices_for_request() 
    `

Comment: It's NOT "choiches", it's "choices" ! Good call @stevejalim